# WordPress PHP version

Tags: php, updates, phpmyadmin

My server has last PHP versión but WordPress still But my site keeps asking for the latest version, how do I update this? Thank you

Comment: I've noticed this also on my sites that have PHP 7.3, but WP still complains about an old version of PHP. My theory is that I'll just ignore that warning, because I know better.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your **`.htaccess`** file. WordPress will check if you have this line:

```
# Use PHP 7.3 as default
```

If it's not the latest PHP version (i.e PHP 5.6), even if you are running the latest version on your host, your dashboard will show that warning.

Answer (score 0):

it's quite simple. You have to log in to your cPanel then go to the PHP option, and there you will be able to see your current PHP version and the available Updates version. Simply, select the version you want to update and apply. If you face any issues, simply check out this tutorial [enter link description here](https://technewsntips.com/how-to-check-your-wordpress-website-php-version/)